# Microsoft purview data access policy not applying

Tags: azure, azure-purview

I am working on this [Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/tutorial-data-owner-policies-storage) from Microsoft Azure team to implement Access provisioning by data owner to Azure Storage datasets. As shown in the image below, the Data Owner Policy is supposed to allow Grady Archie a `Read` permission on `Azure Data Lake Gen2` storage account called `acct4dlsgen2`. But for some reasons, when Grady Archie logs into Azure portal in the same network, he is unable to access `acct4dlsgen2` storage.

**Question**: What I may be doing wrong, and how can we fix the issue?

**Remarks**:

1. I have satisfied all the [prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/tutorial-data-owner-policies-storage#prerequisites) of the same article mentioned above.
2. Have also given Grady Archie the `Read` permissions on the [Purview Collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/quickstart-create-collection) where this storage account is registered in Purview.
3. When I give Grady Archie a `Read` permission directly by going
   through that storage account via Azure portal, Grady Archie can
   access that storage after he logs-in. But this defeats the purpose of implementing Data Access using Purview as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/concept-policies-data-owner#overview) by Microsoft team.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One of the pre-requisites you have done is to configure the subscription for Purview policies using [a PowerShell script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/tutorial-data-owner-policies-storage#configure-the-subscription-where-the-azure-storage-account-resides-for-policies-from-microsoft-purview)

But this configuration is only applied to **newly created storage accounts**. And maybe your storage account was already existing when you configured the subscription for purview policies

if you create a new storage account inside your subscription, I believe your purview policies will work on this account.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your thoughts. I have the same issue on `Self-Service Data Access Policy` as posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77492348/1232087).